# how to get javascript to not rounding a number with 0 decimal to a whole number

Tags: javascript, decimal, rounding, strict

Is there a way to get JS to not round a number with a 0 decimal to a whole number? ex var = 100.0 //100? I know this isn't a regular thing to do in JS but it's needed to port a method from a processing library which im porting to processing.js. the method uses strict typed floats/ints to decided whether its a float or int/color value.

thanks

Comment: `typeof 100.1 === typeof 100`, so how would it do strict typing?

Comment: Any way to output that value as a string in your program?

Answer (score 0):

There is no integer in JavaScript, there are only floats. So trying to figure out if it is an int or float is basically impossible.